# Rails 3.2 Time Column Not Saving (Simple_Form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I am unable to save data into a time field. What I am finding is that that data is submitted, and I have the following in the parameters array.

```
timefield_datetime(1i) => "",
timefield_datetime(2i) => "",
timefield_datetime(3i) => "",
timefield_datetime(4i) => "2",
timefield_datetime(5i) => "3"
```

Which is supposed to save is 02 hours and 03 minutes.

When it gets to the SQL query creation it leaves out the field. In the insert statement it inserts Null, and when updating it just ignores the field.

The column in the database is defined as a time field.

I am also using simple_form for the form rendering, and have the field setup as:

```
f.input :timefield, :include_blank => true, :as => :time
```

I tried setting the column as a :datetime, but can still not save the data unless I remove the :as => :time, and must submit all parts of the datetime field.

Any ideas why I can not just submit and save the time field?

Answer (score 0):

The version of rails I was using was 3.2.0, the current stable version is 3.2.6.

This was a bug in 3.2.0 and has been fixed in one of the releases on the way from 3.2.0 -> 3.2.6